# How to handle `Crossfade` only for some states in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In Android Compose UI, I'm using `Crossfade` animation to transition between my Composables. The problem is I don't want to have the `Crossfade` for Composable `Intro` to Comopsable `Loading`, but for the other.
Currently I came up with something like this, but it reads a bit weird, any suggestions?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomCrossfade(state: UIState) {
    if (state is UIState.Loading) {
        // When in the Loading state, directly show the IntroView without animation
        IntroView(isLoading = true)
    } else {
        // For all other states, use Crossfade to animate transitions
        Crossfade(targetState = state, animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)) { animatedState ->
            when (animatedState) {
                is UIState.Intro -> IntroView(isLoading = false)
                is UIState.Quote -> QuoteComposable(quote = animatedState.quote)
                is UIState.Error -> ErrorComposable(errorMessage = animatedState.errorMessage)
                // Loading state is already handled outside of Crossfade
                is UIState.Loading -> {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine. The other option is just having an `else ->` instead of `is UIState.Loading ->` or omitting that line altogether.

Alternatively, you could collapse your Loading and Quote states into one:

```
enum class UiState {
  INTRO, QUOTE, ERROR
}
val uiState = when (state) {
  is Loading, is Intro -> INTRO
  is Quote -> QUOTE
  is Error -> ERROR
}
Crossfade(targetState = uiState) { animatedState ->
  when (animatedState) {
    INTRO -> IntroView(state is Loading)
    QUOTE -> QuoteComposable((state as Quote).quote)
    ERROR -> ErrorComposable((state as Error).errorMessage)
  }
}
```

Make sure you check that all status updates are propagated correctly if you do this, using `derivedState` if needed

I'm not sure if this is actually better than your original solution. I would probably prefer your version for code that needs to be readable.

Comment: Having `uiState` is way to go, nice.